# Is there any detailed documentation on the Endpoint class generator?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

The only docs I can find say say "click 'generate endpoint class' and then something magic happens".

I'm looking for a bit more detail.

Specifically what I am trying to achieve is to generate Endpoint classes that use Objectify in place of JDO for persistence.

For clarity, I am **not** interested in generating client classes since I will be accessing the endpoints from Erlang.

Answer (score 0):

All the features that you describe are things you need to do in your own server-side logic.  Those are not generated for you.  After that, you need to annotate your APIs (entry points).

Then you can use the endpoint tools to generate the endpoint classes on the client side.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/annotations

Comment: I fully realise I need to do these things myself. The way I would like to do them is to do them once by modifying the template that the Endpoint class generator is using. That way, each generated Endpoint class contains my custom persistence code. I'm not using client classes, but if ever I did, my generated classes will still conform to the same method signature, so my custom persistence logic would be invisible.

The alternative is I don't use the Endpoint generator and hand craft each Endpoint class, which is a major pain.